# Statically get base class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++20, type-traits, c++23

Is there a way to statically (i.e. at compile time) get the base class of a given class?

That is, given:

```
class Base {};
class Derived1: public Base {};
class Derived2: public Derived1 {};
class Derived3: public Derived2 {};
```

For example `is_base_of<Base,Derived3>` gives true.

I'd like to know if there is something like `base_of<Derived3>` that would give `Base`.

In case, there is a solution (which I doubt), I'd also like to know if there is a possibility to get the direct child of `Base`. For example something like `base_child_of<Derived3>` would give `Derived1`.

**ADDENDUM**

Here is a not so beautiful solution but it does the job. Especially, I do not like to have to write two time the class parent name (for example: `class Derived2 : public Derived1 { HIERARCHY(Derived1)  };` but I didn't find any solution that doesn't impair the curly brackets in most IDE editors, by adding one in the define):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define HIERARCHY(PARENT) public: using inherited = PARENT;     using base = inherited::base;

class Base { public: using base = Base; };
class Derived1 : public Base     { HIERARCHY(Base    )  };
class Derived2 : public Derived1 { HIERARCHY(Derived1)  };
class Derived3 : public Derived2 { HIERARCHY(Derived2)  };

// Expands to:
// class Base { public: using base = Base; };
// class Derived1 : public Base     { public: using inherited = Base;     using base = inherited::base; };
// class Derived2 : public Derived1 { public: using inherited = Derived1; using base = inherited::base; };
// class Derived3 : public Derived2 { public: using inherited = Derived2; using base = inherited::base; };

// Not really needed anymore, now CLASS::base does the stuff
// (I leave it here to illustrate how a static loop/recursion may be performed)
template <typename CLASS>
struct base_of {
 using type = typename std::conditional<
      std::is_same<CLASS, Base>::value,
      CLASS,
      typename std::conditional<
         std::is_base_of<typename CLASS::base, CLASS>::value,
         typename base_of<typename CLASS::inherited>::type,
         CLASS
      >::type
   >::type;
};

template<>
struct base_of<Base> {
 using type = Base;
};

template <typename CLASS>
struct direct_child_of_base_of {
 using type = typename std::conditional<
                  std::is_same<typename CLASS::inherited, typename CLASS::base>::value,
                  CLASS,
                  typename direct_child_of_base_of<typename CLASS::inherited>::type
               >::type;
};

template<>
struct direct_child_of_base_of<Base> {
 using type = void;
};

int main() {
 std::cout << "dbase_of<Derived3>: " << typeid(base_of<Derived3>::type).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "dbase_of<Derived2>: " << typeid(base_of<Derived2>::type).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "dbase_of<Derived1>: " << typeid(base_of<Derived1>::type).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "dbase_of<Base    >: " << typeid(base_of<Base    >::type).name() << std::endl;

 std::cout << std::endl;

// This is equivalent
 std::cout << "Derived3::base: " << typeid(Derived3::base).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "Derived2::base: " << typeid(Derived2::base).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "Derived1::base: " << typeid(Derived1::base).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "Base    ::base: " << typeid(Base    ::base).name() << std::endl;

 std::cout << std::endl;

 std::cout << "direct_child_of_base_of<Derived3>: " << typeid(direct_child_of_base_of<Derived3>::type).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "direct_child_of_base_of<Derived2>: " << typeid(direct_child_of_base_of<Derived2>::type).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "direct_child_of_base_of<Derived1>: " << typeid(direct_child_of_base_of<Derived1>::type).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "direct_child_of_base_of<Base    >: " << typeid(direct_child_of_base_of<Base    >::type).name() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output is (with GCC):

```
base_of<Derived3>: 4Base
base_of<Derived2>: 4Base
base_of<Derived1>: 4Base
base_of<Base    >: 4Base

Derived3::base: 4Base
Derived2::base: 4Base
Derived1::base: 4Base
Base    ::base: 4Base

direct_child_of_base_of<Derived3>: 8Derived1
direct_child_of_base_of<Derived2>: 8Derived1
direct_child_of_base_of<Derived1>: 8Derived1
direct_child_of_base_of<Base    >: v
```

Comment: The technique to do this is reflection and C++ dose not offer that yet.  There is experimental support and some libraries, but nothing standard.

Comment: A class can have multiple base classes, so what would this supposed `base_of<>` return in that case?

Comment: 101th time this question  pops up and every time there is same issue: what about plural inheritance? virtual inheritance? Should private base class be accessible? Those things do not  exist in Java and alike and seems people assume that it's same in C++

Comment: Yes, it's easy:  `template <typename T> using base_of = is_base_of<Base, T>;`

Comment: @Eljay I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, the direct base class (in opposition to indirect base classes). Seems obvious to me, despite the comment of Swift - Friday Pie. Keep things simple. I don't pretend that it would solve all cases, but it would anyway solve more cases that today.

Comment: There are several solutions to the question, but they depend on how it is intended to be used, and what problem is trying to be solved.  The simplest I can think of is "do it yourself", *à la* `class Derived1: public Base { public: using base = Base; };` and now `Derived1::base` is how to statically get the base class type of the Derived1 class.  (Although I'd use `super` rather than `base`.)

Comment: @Eljay I was indeed working on such a a solution while you posted you last command. I will add an addendum to my question in a few minutes.

Comment: BTW I don't put what's I've added in the addendum as a answer because this is definitely not what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, with some limitations, by using stateful metaprogramming to record the type deduced for a universal conversion operator used to construct the subobjects of the derived type in aggregate initialization (assuming it is an aggregate). For example, we can write:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct first_direct_base {
    template<class U>
    struct Y {
        friend auto f(first_direct_base*) { return U(); }
    };
    friend auto f(first_direct_base*);
    struct A {
        template<class U, int = sizeof(Y<U>)>
        operator U();
    };
    using type = decltype(T{A{}}, f((first_direct_base*)0));
};
template<class T>
using first_direct_base_t = first_direct_base<T>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qrETEPcv9).

For a fuller explanation of this technique, see http://alexpolt.github.io/type-loophole.html

If you're happy with using manual reflection, I'd recommend [Boost.Describe](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#classes). For example, with the above you might write:

```cpp
class Base { BOOST_DESCRIBE_CLASS(Base, (), (), (), ()) };
class Derived1: public Base { BOOST_DESCRIBE_CLASS(Derived1, (Base), (), (), ()) };

template<class T>
using first_direct_base_t = boost::mp11::mp_front<
    boost::describe::describe_bases<T, boost::describe::mod_public>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently no, not in standard C++.

There are reflection proposals that are being worked on.  The original plan was to have them published in [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23), but between an improved syntax proposal and the Covid-19 pandemic, it was postponed.

When reflection arrives, this will be possible.  The syntax was still in flux last I checked.  Either [c++26](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b26) or [c++29](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b29).